# How to ask a semaphore for returning immediately rather than wait for signal?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I'd like to efficiently implement this behaviour:

A function is asked to run (by the user). Knowing that this function is also automatically repeatedly called by a timer, I'd like to make sure the function returns whenever it is already running.

In pseudo code:

```
var isRunning = false

func process() {

    guard isRunning == false else { return }

    isRunning = true

    defer {
        isRunning = false
    }

    // doing the job
}
```

I am aware of the semaphore concept:

```
let isRunning = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

func process() {

    // *but this blocks and then passthru rather than returning immediately if the semaphore count is not zero.    
    isRunning.wait()

    defer {
        isRunning.signal()
    }

    // doing the job
}
```

How would you use the semaphore to implement this behaviour with a semaphore OR any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `wait(timeout:)` with a timeout value of `now()` to test the
semaphore. If the semaphore count is zero then this returns `.timedOut`,
otherwise it returns `.success` (and decreases the semaphore count).

```
let isRunning = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

func process() {
    guard isRunning.wait(timeout: .now()) == .success  else {
        return // Still processing
    }
    defer {
        isRunning.signal()
    }

    // doing the job
}
```